# MySQL Inner Join should not produce results ... but it does

Tags: mysql, join

I've come across a situation where an incorrect query was generated:

```
select a.id, e.ethnicity_cd, e.appl_person_id from applicants a
inner join ucpsom_production_ucpsom_production.ETHNICITY e
on e.appl_person_id = a.id
where a.amc_id = 12977319
```

The error is in the join statement. The statement should read "`e.appl_person_id = a.appl_person_id`" and return no records because there is no `e.appl_person_id` value equal to  "80cbacb2-8444-11df-acd2-12313b079cc4", the `a.id` value.

What is happening then is that MySQL is matching values of 80 (for e.appl_person_id) to values of "80cbacb2-8444-11df-acd2-12313b079cc4" (for a.id). Thus:

> 80 = "80cbacb2-8444-11df-acd2-12313b079cc4".

*Note: e.app_person_id is a decimal and a.id is a string.* It looks like MySQl is comparing the first two characters of the a.id value to the e.appl_person_id value.

Can anyone explain why this is happening with MySQL, and also, is this MySQL specific in nature?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like MySQL is attempting to do an [implicit conversion of data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html) (from string to int in this case).

Most databases will do some conversions implicitly, for example SQL server will implicitly convert from `smallint` to `int`, but which conversions are done implicitly would be DBMS specific.

Comment: Thanks much for the reference. Explains it all!